# ¿Cómo puedo generar ID autoincremental?

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente código y siempre me genera el mismo ID, alguien sabe como puedo generar un ID automático que vaya incrementando su valor?(1,2,3,4 etc).

Sin tener que crear un variable global

```
    public boolean agregarPelicula(String Pelicula) throws Exception{
        
        boolean existePelicula = false;
        int cont = 1;

        for(Pelicula p : catagolo) {
            if(p.getIdPelicula()==cont) {
                existePelicula = true;
                throw new Exception("Ya existe esa pelicula");
            }
        }
        if(!existePelicula) {       
            Pelicula aux = new Pelicula(cont, Pelicula);
            this.catagolo.add(aux);
            cont++;
        }
        return existePelicula;
    }
```

Comment: Estas utilizando algun motor de base de datos en particular?. Si es asi, deberias dejar que el motor de DB maneje los ids él.

Comment: Hola, para poder ayudarte deberías mostrar la clase Pelicula, ver si estás utilizando "JPA" para la persistencia de datos, o si sencillamente tienes un contador asociado a la clase para asignarle el id a la siguiente película en función del total de películas insetadas. En cuanto al contador que tienes en ese método, una vez acaba se reiniciará siempre a 1.

Comment: Sin usar variable global? o sin usar base de datos? tal vez una lista que vaya guardando las películas o por lo menos los id, y de esa lista buscar el ultimo id o dependiendo del orden en que que se vayan agregando las películas, buscar el id mas alto, y aumentar 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que siempre que llamas la función lo inicializas en 1, en algún lugar debes tener el último, puede ser de la base de datos o desde el lugar que llamas la función.

Incluso podrías ponerlo como parámetro de la función, para que cuando la llames, este inicie desde el último + 1 y no desde 1.

Con la parte que muestras es díficil ayudarte.

Te recomiendo investigar cómo puedes obtener el id de la última pelicula y a ese le sumas  uno; Así obtienes un id que no ha sido usado.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribuciòn, te sugerimos revisar [ask], saludos.